# How can I stop QFrames joining when added into a QVBoxLayout (PyQt5)

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

this is my qframe object

```
class PlaylistItem(QFrame):
    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    def __init__(self, name, filename):
        super(PlaylistItem, self).__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.file = filename
        self.widgetUi()

    def widgetUi(self):
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setStyleSheet("QFrame{background-color: grey; border-radius: 10}")
        layout = self.layout
        nlab = QLabel(self.name)
        layout.addWidget(nlab)
        buttons = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(buttons)
        playbut = QPushButton("Play")
        rembut = QPushButton("Remove")
        buttons.addWidget(playbut)
        buttons.addWidget(rembut)
```

this is my scrollarea with a vboxlayout in a widget

```
self.playlist = QScrollArea()
self.playlist.setWidgetResizable(True)
self.playlistwidget = QWidget()
self.playlistbox = QVBoxLayout()
self.playlistwidget.setLayout(self.playlistbox)
self.playlist.setWidget(self.playlistwidget)
```

Here I am adding the qframes into the vboxlayout

```
for name in range(10):
    but = PlaylistItem("Test Song"+str(name), "test")
    self.playlistbox.insertWidget(self.playlistbox.count()-1, but)
```

This is my result

[image: I get this]

i dont want all the qframes joining. i want them as separate qframes in their own grey rounded rectangle bg

Comment: Why are you creating the layout for the class?

Comment: @musicamante sorry, didnt get you

Comment: you're creating the layout as a *class* attribute, which is clearly wrong, since it shouldn't be shared amongst all instances. Read my answer, and do research about classes and instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A layout should be an *instance* attribute, while you're creating only a single layout as a *class attribute*, which means that the **same** layout is being *shared* for every new instance of `PlaylistItem`.

The result is that every time a new PlaylistItem is created, the contents of the previous will be *reparented* to the new. At the end of the for loop, you'll have 9 completely empty QFrames, and the last one will have all the previously created labels and buttons instead. This is also the reason for the big margin on top of the frame: that space is actually the sum of the spacings between the (now) empty frames.

You should be much more careful when using class attributes, since the are always shared amongst *all instances* (unless they are overwritten by instance attributes).

```
class PlaylistItem(QFrame):
    # ...
    def widgetUi(self):
        # the following line automatically sets the layout on the current
        # widget instance, so you don't need to call `setLayout()`
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        # values should always specify units, even if `px` is often assumed
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            QFrame {
                background-color: grey;
                border-radius: 10px;
            }
        """)
        nlab = QLabel(self.name)
        layout.addWidget(nlab)
        buttons = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(buttons)
        playbut = QPushButton("Play")
        rembut = QPushButton("Remove")
        buttons.addWidget(playbut)
        buttons.addWidget(rembut)
```

<sup>I suggest you to do some more studying on classes, instances, methods and instances.</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much. I had a lot of empty space before the qframes in the scroll area
`you'll have 9 completely empty QFrames` which was this.

`I suggest you to do some more studying on classes, instances, methods and instances` surely will do